# POST method handling in struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-interceptors

We have a form where we take some input from User and then submit that form to a Struts2 Action via HTTP POST Method.

But If we try to submit the same form with HTTP GET Method, struts2 processes the request which is not the behavior we want.

What we want to have some sort of configuration on Action level in Struts2 where we can define the HTTPMethod type that particular Action suppose to handle like 
in struts.xml :

```
<action name="ABCAction" class="foo.bar.ABCActoinClass" method="abcAction" RequestMethod="POST">
</action>
```

we want something like what we have in SpringMVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ABCController", method = RequestMethod.POSTproduces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
```

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't exist. (Nor is there any terrific reason for it to, but whatever.) There are any number of ways you could handle this, the simplest is to just check the request type and 404 if it's a GET. I generally either (a) didn't care, or (b) used a custom annotation to handle it, or (c) did a trivial interceptor that routed requests to appropriately-named handlers, e.g., `executePost` etc.